# Criar uma Lista HTML com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, front-end

Olá, sou iniciante em programação e estou aprendendo a integrar JS nos meus códigos HTML... me propus a fazer um "programa" que receba o nome de  produtos e suas classes (já pré definidia em uma caixa de option) e retorne esses produtos listados pelas suas classes. Ja consigo fazer o JS receber as informações e imprimir no console, mas nao sei como posso ediar as `<li>` do meu html segue o código:

codigo HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel=stylesheet href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel=stylesheet href="css/style.css">
        
        <title>Lista de Compras</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <section class="app">
                <h1>LISTA DE COMPRAS</h1>
                <form id="formulario">
                    <label for="produto">Produto:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="produto" class="caixa" name="produto" required placeholder="Insira o alimento desejado.">
            

                    <fieldset class="categoria">
                        <legend id="legenda">Qual é a categoria desse produto?</legend>
                        <select id="selecao" name="categoria">
                            <option class="item" id="itemFruta">Fruta</option>
                            <option class="item" id="itemLaticinio">Laticinio</option>
                            <option class="item" id="itemCongelado">Congelado</option>
                            <option class="item" id="itemDoce">Doce</option>
                        </select>
                    </fieldset>
                    <input type="submit" value="Listar produto" id="enviar">
                </form>
            </section>

            <section class="resposta">
                <h2>Sua lista de compras está separada em:</h2>
                <ul id="lista">
                    <li>
                        <h3 class="categoria.lista">Fruta:</h3>
                        <p id=".fruta"> </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3 class="categoria.lista">Laticinio:</h3>
                        <p id=".laticinio"> </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3 class="categoria.lista">Congelado:</h3>
                        <p id=".congelado"> </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h3 class="categoria.lista">Doce:</h3>
                        <p id=".doce"> </p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </main>
    </body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

codigo js:

```
btnSalvar.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const formulario = document.querySelector("#formulario");
    console.log(formulario.produto.value);
    console.log(formulario.categoria.value);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro seria bom você editar os `id` dos elementos `p` pois está com um ponto na frente, e ponto na frente é atalho para o CSS entender que trata-se de uma `class`. Pode deixar assim: `<p id="fruta">`. Mas, se isso realmente é para aplicar os estilos CSS de uma classe chamada fruta, então é só trocar de `id=` para `class=`, porém também nesse caso tire os pontos da frente (por exemplo: `class="fruta"`).

Feito isso, no seu script você pode ir concatenando os valores de várias formas, mas vou sugerir localizando o `p` correspondente da categoria e depois ir concatenando pelo `innerHTML`. O script ficaria assim:

```
const btnSalvar = document.querySelector("#enviar");
    
btnSalvar.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const formulario = document.querySelector("#formulario");
    const produto = formulario.produto.value; // pega o value do produto
    const categoria = formulario.categoria.value.toLowerCase(); // toLowerCase para ficar tudo minúsculo
    const p = document.querySelector("#" + categoria); // pega o 'p' correspondente pelo id da categoria em questão
    
    // Agora é a parte que vai concatenar os valores.
    // Aqui está de uma forma que, caso o p esteja vazio, apenas concatena o produto. Caso não esteja vazio, coloca
    // uma vírgula antes de concatenar.
    if (p.innerHTML == "") {
        p.innerHTML += produto;
    }
    else {
        p.innerHTML += ", " + produto;
    }
});
```

Para o exemplo acima eu também removi aquele espaço entre os `p` (para dar certo na hora do if ver se o p está ou não vazio), troquei disso:
`<p id="fruta"> </p>`
para isso:
`<p id="fruta"></p>`